# How do I pass a function with parameters to child element in react and immediately invoke it?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Let's say I have this function in the parent component which just mutates the text formatting:

```
combineName(name) {
    const joinName = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return joinName[0].toLowerCase() + joinName.substr(1);
}
```

Then in my parent component's render() method, I have:

```
render() {
  return (
    <h1 id={this.combineName.bind(this, name)()}>
  )
}
```

Which immediately invokes the combineName function upon render. This is working. However inside my parent component, I also have a child component like so:

```
<SectionBody
    combineName={this.combineName}
/>
```

My problem is how do I use this inside the child component in the way I used it in the parent component?

Do I simply call it like so:

`this.props.combineName(param)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.props.combineName(param)
```

this should work like a charm.

I would prefer to make these changes as well, I think you're binding it in your constructor but still it's preferable to use es6 arrow function which auto binds this to handler:

```
  combineName = name => {
    const joinName = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return joinName[0].toLowerCase() + joinName.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to call it like

```
this.props.combineName(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine:

```
<SectionBody
    combineName={this.props.combineName}
/>
```

Comment: hi @Bhojendera. combineName is is parent adn `SectionBody` is rendering in parent as well